# Eliminating small polygons using ModelBuilder to iterate through feature classes?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select, iterator

I created four large polygon feature classes of surface slope classes from a grid of 6-foot cells covering half my county. In order to repair the geometry and eliminate small polygons I broke four polygon feature classes into 115 polygon feature classes.

Now I'd like to remove small polygons from each of these polygon feature classes because the small bits take up a lot of memory and aren't important at the scale of analyses I'll be doing.

I tried using ModelBuilder with a Feature Class Iterator to go through the polygon feature classes, but I could not figure out how to select the small polygons in the active feature class. In order to use the Eliminate tool, there has to be a selection of features to eliminate. The problem is there does not seem to be a way to use the iterator variable as an input to the Select by Attribute tool.

I'd sure appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction to get this process automated.

[Using ArcGIS 10.1 ArcInfo license on 64-bit Windows 7 workstation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to feed the output of the iterator (green blob) into a make featurelayer tool which would then feed into your selectbyattribute tool.